# Symfony2 / Twig syntax

Tags: symfony, twig

I' ve got probably stupid question.

What is the difference in this code?

```
  {{ include('QABundle:User:user-list.html.twig',{ 'documents': documents }) }}
  {% include "QABundle:User:user-list.html.twig" with { 'paginator' : paginator} %}
```

I mean why in first line is " {{ ", and in the second " {% ".
Is there any difference? They both works well for m, but I'm just curious.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As you stated, both of these pretty much do the same.

But, the first one does a bit more - you can pass the returned template to another function, filter, etc...

Answer (score 1):

They do exactly the same thing, except that generally speaking a function allows you to do some things that you can't do using a tag.

For example, if you want to get the rendered content of a template and use it whatever you want (set a variable, use a filter, ...etc) you've to use the `include()` function,

```
{% set my_content = include('my_template.html.twig') %}
{{ include('my_template.html.twig')|myFilter }}
```